# reCaptcha Enterprise score-based, handling the score in the frontend

Tags: go, svelte, recaptcha, sveltekit

I've built a short draft of an implementation of the `reCaptcha Enterprise` solution using score-based site keys.

My frontend is developed using `SvelteKit`. I didn't make a build yet, but in the end, it is intended to be built as a **static website**.

## Case 1: browse action

The user is not authenticated, he's just browsing some pages. My understanding is that `reCaptcha` just needs to be fed with some browsing data to make some stats. Here is what I wrote:

```js
// when the recaptcha library is ready... 
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async function () {
  // We send the `site-key`
  // corresponding to the `browse_product_page_1` action.
  // Note: I assumed that there's one site-key per action.
  const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(
    'xxx',
    { action: 'browse_product_page_1' }
  );

  // We send the token received with the action name to the backend for validation
  // the backend (in golang) make a call to recaptcha and return a score
  try {
    const payload = `{
        "action_token": "${token}",
        "action_name": "browse_product_page_1"
    }`;
    const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_API}/captcha`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload
    });

    // We parse the json response
    const data = await res.json();
    if (!res.ok) throw new ServerError(res.status, data.message);
        
    // If the score is too low
    if (data.score < 0.5) {
       // We replace the content body with an error message
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err) // TODO better error handling
  }
});
```

### Question

If a bot comes in and just crawls the website without javascript enabled, the reCaptcha request is not made and it won't work, am I correct? If so, what am I missing here?

## Case 2: sign-up action

This time, the user creates an account by sending his **email** and **password**.

```js
<script>
function signUp(){
   // validation of the email and pass...
   ...

   // We send the `site-key` corresponding to the `signup` action.
   const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(
        'xxx',
        { action: 'signup' }
    );
   // We send the token to the backend for validation which returns a score
   try {
    const payload = `{
        "action_token": "${token}",
        "action_name": "signup"
    }`;
    const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_API}/captcha`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload
    });

    // We parse the json response
    const data = await res.json();
    if (!res.ok) throw new ServerError(res.status, data.message);
        
    // If the score is too low
    if (data.score < 0.5) {
         // return an error message
    }
    
    // create the account (after sending a confirmation email)
}
</script>
<div class="sign-up">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
  <input type="hidden" name="captcha-token" id="captcha-token" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="sign-up" on:click={signUp}/> // ON CLICK -> signUp
</div>
```

### Question

Would a bot be able to span the submit button here?

If so, I was thinking about trying to send the recaptcha token along with the email and password to the backend API to validate the token and create the account. That would couple the account creation with the token validation but I think it's acceptable. What do you think?

Many thanks